# Allow only numbers and colons in Safari and Chrome on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, webkit, onkeyup, mobile-webkit

I am using the following code to prevent certain characters from being entered into a textbox. It works fine except for Chrome and Safari (webkit mobile?) on iPads and iPhones. Works fine on Macs in Safari and Chrome. Any ideas how to restrict to just numbers and colons for those devices?

```
jQuery.fn.forceNumeric = function (allowDecimal, allowColon)
{
    return this.each(function ()
    {
        $(this).keydown(function (e)
        {
            var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

            if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey &&
            // numbers   
                    key >= 48 && key <= 57 ||
            // Numeric keypad
                    key >= 96 && key <= 105 ||
            // period, comma, minus adn period on keypad
            //      key == 190 ||   // period
            //      key == 188 ||   // comma
            //      key == 109 ||   // minus
            //      key == 110 ||   // period on keypad
            // Backspace and Tab and Enter
                    key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 13 ||
            // Home and End
                    key == 35 || key == 36 ||
            // left and right arrows
                    key == 37 || key == 39 ||
            // Del and Ins
                    key == 46 || key == 45)
                return true;
            else if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && allowDecimal && key == 190) // period
                return true;
            else if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && allowDecimal && key == 110) // period on keypad
                return true;
            else if (e.shiftKey && (key == 186 || key == 59) && allowColon) // colon (ie & chrome = 186, ff = 59)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

We use similar logic (keyCode 48-75 and 96-105) and it works.  I haven't tested your example code, but your first `if` statement that is making heavy use of `&&` and `||` without parenthesis give me a little concern.  Maybe try putting in some parenthetical groups and try it again?

Comment: I've discovered that it's because on an iPad or iPhone you don't have to press the Shift key to access the colon. But if I allow key 186 without requiring Shift, it allows the user to enter a semicolon too, which I want to prevent.

Comment: Not the cleanest solution, but you could add in a test against the useragent for iphone / ipad.  Like:  e.shiftKey || (/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent))

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing - detecting for iOS devices and adding an else to the original script. There may be a better way...

```
function isiPhone(){
    return (
        //Detect iPhone
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) ||
        //Detect iPod
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1)
    );
}

var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

...
else if ((isiPhone() || isiPad) && (key == 186 || key == 59) && allowColon) // colon   (iOS devices don't have a shift key)
                return true;
```